# Rails: Send mail at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I have two subscription plans with `Braintree`, one is a six month plan and the other is a full year plan, both plans have ids. I did the implementation via api, thus the data is saved on their end only.

I would like to send out an email notification to the users x-days before the subscription expires.

The `Braintree` support team gave me the following code in order to find the subscription with 1 billing cycle remaining:

```
  search_results = Braintree::Subscription.search do |search|
    search.billing_cycles_remaining <= 1
end
```

I'm kind of stuck on how to check the above code every day an how to implement the email notification ... should I use `rake test` to send emails or `delayed_jobs`?? 
or is there another way to implement this??
and how can I finalize the above code??

Comment: you could do this a couple ways. As pointed out in an answer the clockwork gem. Active Job (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#creating-a-job) or create a crontab job that runs a 'billing' process (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

Comment: Use `sidekiq` and `redis`, you can stack the mails in a queue and set a specific time to send them

Comment: There is `rufus-scheduler` which is quite easy to setup, assuming you dont want a backend job for it - https://richonrails.com/articles/background-tasks-with-rufus-scheduler - You can specify a date dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

use [clockwork gem](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) and follow this [blog](https://blog.anynines.com/how-to-schedule-background-jobs-using-the-clockwork-gem/), this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)! There are lots of gems out there that can help you use crontabs with a Ruby app. Many of the ones listed [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling.html) use cron.